# How to make a list from a text file

Tags: python, list, text

Let's say I have a text file:

```
one #first column
two

three four #second column, same text file
 five
six
```

Now how would you make a list like this using that text file:

```
['one', 'two'] #first column list
['three', 'four', 'five', 'six'] #second column list from the same text file
```

I suppose this can be done by using `split()` or `splitlines()`?

Comment: are `three` and `four` really on the same line in the txt file?

Comment: I think you can use re regular expression operations module
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: My text file is about 3000 lines long and looks messy, there are some words in the same line, I spent some time trying to clean the text file with a script and I did as much as I can and it's still messy. Problem is that I'm scraping a big table and I need each row in a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
import re

with open('my_file.txt') as fp:
    l = fp.read()

col = l.split('\n\n')
columns = [c.split()  for c in col]
columns
```

output:

```
[['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four', 'five', 'six']]
```

you can access the columns by index, for the first column you can use:

```
columns[0]
```

output:

```
['one', 'two']
```

Comment: Just use `c.split()`, no need for `re`.

Comment: I had to use col = l.split('\n ') and now everything is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a character to separate your columns on every line, like ";". Then, consider here an exemple of a file with 5 lines :

```py
file = open("foo.txt", "rw+")
line = file.readlines()
print("Read Line: %s" % (line))

line = file.readlines(2)
print("Read Line: %s" % (line))
# Close opened file
file.close()
```

You can learn more about it, this is a very simple thing called "readlines". So just search for documentation...
Then you can use the split command,  with the syntax :

```py
x = yourstring.split(separator, maxsplit)
```

x is now a list of strings.
Just ignore maxsplit, your separator is here in my case ";".
So you got your strings with your lines that you will split into columns : use split to get then a list of list of strings. You're still here ? XD

Then, I won't show you the full code, that's too easy. You got all the tools you need to do this, and obtain a list with many lists inside, your lines. Into these lists, you got strings, your columns. Then, little hint, use a for i in range(len(won't say you what)) to append to a column 1 list element n°1, to a column 2 list, element n°2, etc... To sort your strings into lists, to get a bit order into this mess !

Ask me if you got any questions, hope I've been clear ;D

The Machinist

Comment: I have tried separating my columns with a char and then tried using split(), had no luck. But I will look into your solution, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome ! Get a bit of documentation about split, ya'll see, it isn't complicated once you understand it.